Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. how to update the android app with the correct key?
I am trying to update android app. I forgot key store path and created a new app bundle and tried to update my app with the new key and this is giving the error Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. Your App Bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with fingerprint:. How can I get the correct key or change it so that I am able to update the app?. Thanks

Follow the instructions from Lost or compromised upload key? to in this article about Play Signing.
